# trying make from excel doc cells a tuple

Tags: python, tuples, xlsx

I have an Excel doc, I'm trying to pull data out and make every cell a tuple member.

```
fm = pd.read_excel("File", sheet_name='Sheet1')
L = []
for row in fm.iterrows():
   for i in row:
     L.append(i)
mytuple = tuple(L)
print(mytuple)
```

But it's not working, and I'm getting only the first row and `NaN`s

Comment: What's "Nans" exactly?

Comment: add your results and desired output

Comment: You should check the content of your excel table.

Answer (score -1):

without provided input and desired output, I can only guess, but try this

lets' assume the returned output from parsing excel is iteratable structure (rows) that contains iteratable (cells) like this

```
excel = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]

L=[]
for row in excel:
  L.append(tuple([i for i in row]))

print L
```

output

```
[(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)]
```

Comment: This will provide the exact same output. All it does is compressing the inner loop to a list comprehension

Comment: @DeepSpace please check the code before you down vote! in this code the output is a list contains tuples of cells `[(cell1,cell2..)..]` the code provide in the question is generating tuple of the cells values like `(cell1,cell2...)`

Comment: no, it doesn't. It produces a list of pd.series, not cells' values.